# Python image resizing, installing PIL

Tags: python, image-processing, image-resizing

I want to do some image resizing with Python. I was trying to do it with the Python Image Library. Am I barking up the right tree?

I tried to install PIL on my Mac from this source http://www.pythonware.com/products/pil/, but it has not been updated since 09. Is there something newer that I should look into?

Installing it gives me an error:

```
unable to execute gcc-4.0: No such file or directory
error: command 'gcc-4.0' failed with exit status 1
```

I tried installing the GCC but I think I have 4.2.1

Any help?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes PIL is the right Module. but can also try ImageMagick

http://www.imagemagick.org/script/index.php

No PIL 1.1.7 IS the LATEST, Nov 15th 2009

you can check this http://passingcuriosity.com/2009/installing-pil-on-mac-os-x-leopard/

Answer (score 0):

PIL is the right module, PIL 1.1.7 might not be the version you want. :-)

In case the link from dilip kumbham doesn't work, a fork of PIL is available at http://pypi.python.org/pypi/Pillow

That project is mostly about fixing packaging issues as far as I can tell, so it might be easier to install in general.